# Encode and decode swiftui MKPlacemark

Tags: swiftui

I am new to SwiftUI and I am trying to encode and decode a MKPlacemark struct to json.

I have the struct defined as below. I am able to display the details in the app but I am not able to decode it.

```
import Foundation 
import MapKit 
import UIKit

struct Landmark {

    let placemark: MKPlacemark
    
    var id: UUID {
        return UUID()
    }
    
    var name: String {
        self.placemark.name ?? ""
    }
    
    var title: String {
        self.placemark.title ?? ""
    }
    
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        self.placemark.coordinate
    }
}
```

I can search for placemarks like this:

```
import Foundation 
import Combine 
import MapKit

class SearchPlaces: NSObject, ObservableObject {

    @Published var searchQuery = ""
    @Published var landmarks: [Landmark] = [Landmark]()
    @Published var items: [MapItem] = [MapItem]()

    public func getNearByLandmarks() {
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.naturalLanguageQuery = searchQuery
        let search = MKLocalSearch(request: request)
        search.start { (response, error) in
            if let response = response {
                let mapItems = response.mapItems
                self.landmarks = mapItems.map {
                    Landmark(placemark: $0.placemark)
                }
                Task {
                    await self.getData()
                }
                print("Lamdmarks \(self.landmarks)")
            }
        }
    }

    private func getData() async {
        guard let landmark = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self.landmarks) else { return }
        
        do {
            let decodedLandmark = try JSONDecoder().decode(Landmark.self, from: landmark)
            print("decodedLandmark \(decodedLandmark.id)")
        } catch {
            print("Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

But I get this error: Error

> The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.

The placemark looks like this in xcode

```
Lamdmarks \[Landmark(placemark: La Hacienda Market, 249 Hillside Blvd, South San Francisco, CA  94080, United States @ \<+37.66312925,-122.40844847\> +/- 0.00m, region CLCircularRegion (identifier:'\<+37.66307481,-122.40861130\> radius 141.17', center:\<+37.66307481,-122.40861130\>, radius:141.17m))
```

How do I decode a MKPlacemark to json when I don't know all of its keys.

I tried this

```
extension NSSecureCoding { func archived() throws -> Data { try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false) } }

extension Data { func unarchived<T: NSSecureCoding>() throws -> T? { try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(self) as? T } }

extension Landmark: Codable {

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var unkeyedContainer = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try unkeyedContainer.encode(placemark.archived())
        try unkeyedContainer.encode(id)
        try unkeyedContainer.encode(name)
        try unkeyedContainer.encode(title)
        try unkeyedContainer.encode(coordinate)
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        placemark = try container.decode(Data.self).unarchived()!
        coordinate = try container.decode(CLLocationCoordinate2D.self, "coordinate")
        id = try container.decode(UUID.self)
        name = placemark.name ?? "no name"
        title = placemark.title ?? "no title"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all never `print(error.localizedDescription)` in a `Codable` context. The generic error message is meaningless.

**Always**

```
print(error)
```

to get the real meaningful `DecodingError`.

---

Second of all don't try to adopt `Codable` by serializing each single property in classes which conform to `NSSecureCoding`. Take advantage of the built-in serialization and also of the `PropertyWrapper` pattern.

This PropertyWrapper converts/serializes `MKPlacemark` to Data and vice versa

```
@propertyWrapper
struct CodablePlacemark {
    var wrappedValue: MKPlacemark
}

extension CodablePlacemark: Codable {
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = try container.decode(Data.self)
        guard let placemark = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchivedObject(ofClass: MKPlacemark.self, from: data) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(
                in: container,
                debugDescription: "Invalid placemark"
            )
        }
        wrappedValue = placemark
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.singleValueContainer()
        let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: wrappedValue, requiringSecureCoding: true)
        try container.encode(data)
    }
}
```

In the `Landmark` struct adopt `Codable` and declare the placemark

```
struct Landmark: Codable {
    @CodablePlacemark var placemark: MKPlacemark
}
```

But the property wrapper makes only sense if **you** encode the placemark.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, that helps me a lot. I updated the code and now I am getting this error. Type 'Dictionary<String, Any>' mismatch: Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead. I can see that the type that I am passing to decoder is of type array: Lamdmarks type Array<Landmark>

Comment: As you encode an array you have to decode `[Landmark].self`